# VueJS - Smooth transition when more text is inserted into div

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have made this directive that basically hides some of the text in a div and when you press the show more button, it shows the entire content. I would like to make the transition a tad slower so it feels nicer.

Is there a way to do this right in the directive? That would be ideal, but I'm not able to figure it out. Any thoughts?

This is my code so far:

```
import i18n from '@/services/i18n';

const breakpoints = {
    mobile: 552,
    tablet: 1024,
    desktop: 1920,
};

let threshold = width => {
    const { mobile, tablet, desktop } = breakpoints;
    if (width <= mobile) {
        return 300;
    } else if (width > mobile && width < tablet) {
        return 600;
    } else if (width > tablet && width < desktop) {
        return 800;
    } else {
        return 1000;
    }
};

function setElement(element, value, width) {
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.classList.add('readmore-button');
    button.innerText = i18n.t('button.show-more');

    if (value.length > threshold(width)) {
        element.innerText = `${value.slice(0, threshold(width))}...`;
        element.appendChild(button);
    } else {
        element.innerText = value;
    }

    element.expand = () => {
        element.innerText = value;
        button.removeEventListener('click', element.expand);
    };

    button.addEventListener('click', element.expand);
}

const directive = {
    bind: (el, { value }) => {
        let wWidth = window.innerWidth;
        setElement(el, value, wWidth);
    },
    update: (el, { value }) => {
        let wWidth = window.innerWidth;
        setElement(el, value, wWidth);
    },
    unbind: el => {
        const button = el.querySelector('button');
        if (!button) {
            return;
        }

        button.removeEventListener('click', el.expand);
    },
};

export default directive;
```

Comment: Take a look at [Enter/Leave & List Transitions](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html)

Comment: I already tried that, didn't get anywhere. Plus, I was kinda trying to do everything in one place (if possble).